# Why are my PayPal payments in Magento 2 showing as "pending"?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment, paypal, magento2.4.5

We are facing Paypal pending payment issues. These issues are not occurring for all the orders. 50% of orders are going pending and 50% of orders are going to successful payment by Paypal.
[image]

Comment: Get the access of PayPal and filter by Order increment id and see what it is telling. If everything seems right contact Paypal. May be some shipping address related issue.

Comment: You can enable paypal logs and check what is happening.